# BigQuery: Using IEEE_DIVIDE in a named column returns Unrecognized name?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to use the IEEE_DIVIDE function in BQ to avoid div by zero errors and return the division in a new column. Numerator being new_user_counts while denominator is user_counts. Both, Num and Den are calculated Counts.

I'm getting below error:
Unrecognized name: new_user_counts at [9:14]

```
SELECT
event_date,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(
DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) = 
DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)), 
user_pseudo_id, 
NULL
)) AS new_user_counts, 
COUNT(DISTINCT(user_pseudo_id)) AS user_counts,
IEEE_DIVIDE(new_user_counts, user_counts) AS percentage_new_users
FROM  `google-analytics-tables.*`
GROUP BY event_date
ORDER BY event_date ASC
```

Can anyone help with this, pls. Thanks.

Comment: You can't use an alias column just declared in the same select, you need use a sub select or repeat the aggregation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use below

```
SELECT
  event_date, 
  new_user_counts, 
  user_counts,
  IEEE_DIVIDE(new_user_counts, user_counts) AS percentage_new_users
FROM (
SELECT
  event_date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(
    DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) = 
    DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)), 
    user_pseudo_id, 
    NULL
  )) AS new_user_counts, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT(user_pseudo_id)) AS user_counts,
FROM  `google-analytics-tables.*`
GROUP BY event_date
ORDER BY event_date ASC
)
```